# CSS Aligning Text Within Divs

Tags: html, css

I want to create a header with a few words aligned to the far left of the header `div` and a few words aligned to the far right. I initially did this by creating `span`s (`.headerLeft` and `.headerRight`) and adjusting the alignment for the portions I wanted aligned. However, this creates problems if I want a `background-color` for my header `div`. Is the best practice solution here to simply add a little inline CSS styling, or is there a better way?

### My Code ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/7jAPX/))

#### HTML

```
<div class="header">
 <span class="headerLeft">Welcome to .</span>
 <span class="headerRight"><a href="login.html">Login</a> | <a
 href ="register.html">Register</a></span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.header {
 width:100%
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 margin-top:0;
 background-color:red;
 text-color:#C14000;
}
.headerLeft {
 float:left;
 text-align:left;
}
.headerRight {
 float:right;
 text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: The `background-color` is fine if you take off `float: left;` from `.headerLeft`. BTW, you should use `color: red;` not `text-color: red;`. `text-color` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This code will fix your problem. The `height` of `#header` will automatically take the `height` from the tallest element inside `#header`.

Another way would be to manually set the `height` for `#header`.

You don't need to style sth inline :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the overflow attribute for the header class to force it to wrap around the inner spans.  see http://jsfiddle.net/PsychegoPro/rnDT8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats in order for the div to have actual height.

This can be achieved by using clearfix. [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-actually-is-clearfix/8554054#8554054)